# Why doesnt <% DateTime.Now.ToString(); %> display the time?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have been doing web developement in HTML, CSS, and javascript for awhile now.

Now im beginning to use ASP .Net because developers are my new job use it.

I used Visual Studio Professional (I get it for free from work) to create my first .net Website in C##

The book I'm reading said to enter `<% DateTime.Now.ToString(); %>`  into it but it doesnt work. When I debug it just shows the default page. Here is my whole code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <p>Welcome to beginning ASP .NET 4 on</p> <% DateTime.Now.ToString(); %> 

</asp:Content>
```

This worked in the book but isn't working for me. 
This is in default.aspx

Here is a fiddle but it doesn't work correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/8xuRe/

Can someone give me some guidance?

Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing

[image]

Comment: also note that this is for asp.net http://dotnetfiddle.net/. please do not use jsfiddle for that purpose. dotnetfiddle currently does not support webforms but it does support console, script and mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a the result of a statement to the output of an ASP.NET page, use `<%= ... %>`:

```
<p>Welcome to beginning ASP .NET 4 on</p> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

**Further Reading**

- [Code Render Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @onTheInternet Try removing the `;`.

Comment: HEY! that worked! thanks stranger. Any tips for a very beginner ASP .net developer? Im quite well versed in html/css so im trying to understand the advantage learning this will give me.

Comment: @onTheInternet [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6k3k4a(v=vs.100).aspx) is the best resource. The advantage of ASP.NET (or any server-side scripting language) is that you can do a lot of stuff on the server. For example, if you need to interact with a database or file system, or if you just want to separate your view from your application logic, then you need some sort of server-side code. Note that your JSFiddle doesn't work because JSFiddle can only be used to test client-side code.

Comment: Noted. thanks. will accept answer when timer lets me.

Comment: @onTheInternet: MSDN is the best source, but try to spend sometime here everyday too. you can learn much from here.